# How to create a ADFilter script for Querying users that are there in our "inactive" OU using powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, active-directory

The CN for the inactive OU is inactive/USERS/Administration/Companyname.

Whenever I give this path for the inactive OU it does not return any results.

Please let me know how can we get the required results. When I try searching it from the AD console it shows the results as there are 1350 users inactive, but I am trying to incorporate it in a powershell script using ADFilter command.

I am trying to incorporate a list of all the users from the "inactive" OU from our Active directory structure into out sharepoint site but not able to list any.

Comment: Do you have a sample of your code thus far?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve that pretty easy with examples on here or from google:

[stack overflow example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369994/powershell-active-directory-limiting-my-get-aduser-search-to-a-specific-ou-an)

[google example](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell-get-aduser-filter.htm)

What you are looking for is -searchbase